# Browserify bundle in browser with exports

Tags: node.js, browserify

How do I access the exports from a Browserify bundle in the browser? Example:

```
// parser.js
exports.parse = parse;
```

Then I'm running

```
browserify lib/parser.js -o www/bundle.js
```

Every tutorial/readme I find ends with `Drop a single <script> tag into your html and you're done!`

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

But how do I run `parse`? The function `require` isn't defined in the browser.

```
var Parser = require('parser');
Parser.parse('hit kommer vi aldrig');
> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way with [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/). Instead of `<script src="bundle.js"></script>`, I use the code below.

```
requirejs(['bundle'], function(Parser) {
    Parser.parseText('text');
    // This is also where you would put angular.bootstrap()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Browserify gives all your code a seperate scope to prevent pollution with global variables. You should make your parser global to access it in the browser.

Put this into your `parser.js`:

```
global.parse = parse;
```

Comment: I want to use it in node, so I need to keep `exports`. There must be another way? :)